# Appending current date and time to XLSX file

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there any issue with the below code? I am getting "java.io.FileNotFoundException:" exception. My requirement is to append the current system date and time to the xlsx file.

```
String date=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("F:\\JobStatus_"+date+".xlsx");
workbook.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

Comment: Have you added throws exception at the end of the method like this  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

Comment: Yes, I did...Will give a try once again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output of your current program will be

```
F:\\JobStatus_09/04/2016 09:10:34.xlsx
```

This will be your final output file path

when OS tries to find the path it will consider / as directories.

```
I suggest you to use _ for date saparator instead of /, space and :
```

use the following code

```
String date=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());

date=date.replaceAll("/","_");
date=date.replaceAll(" ","_");
date=date.replaceAll(":","_");

 FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("F:\\JobStatus_"+date+".xlsx");
 workbook.write(fileOut);
 fileOut.close();
```